# Convert utc datetime by timezoName using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui

I have get utc datetime from database.I want to display this utc datetime by user timezone name.So how can i solved this problems using javascript
?If you have any idea please share with me this problems.

Comment: not clear what issue is since javascript `Date()` will already do that automatically

Comment: Check out moment-timezone http://momentjs.com/timezone/. Date() is easier if you want it to just be the user's timezone, but moment will let you specify the timezone by name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript

Comment: Ok jason Kennaly and Shishir KUshwaha .I have try this function.There is some issue like that moment(...).tz is not a function..I also download  'moment-timezone-all-years.min.js '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY [Moment Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)

```
var newYork    = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York");
var losAngeles = newYork.clone().tz("America/Los_Angeles");
var london     = newYork.clone().tz("Europe/London");

newYork.format();    // 2014-06-01T12:00:00-04:00
losAngeles.format(); // 2014-06-01T09:00:00-07:00
london.format();     // 2014-06-01T17:00:00+01:00
```

**DEMO:**

```js
var newYork    = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York");
var losAngeles = newYork.clone().tz("America/Los_Angeles");
var london     = newYork.clone().tz("Europe/London");


$('#newYork').html(newYork.format());
$('#losAngeles').html(losAngeles.format());
$('#london').html(london.format());
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>

<p><strong>newYork:</strong> <span id="newYork"></span></p>
<p><strong>losAngeles:</strong> <span id="losAngeles"></span></p>
<p><strong>london:</strong> <span id="london"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to convert to local time.

```
var date = new Date('6/29/2011 4:52:48 PM UTC');
date.toString() // "Wed Jun 29 2011 09:52:48 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
```

Other wise use timezone offset to convert to local time:

```
function convertUTCDateToLocalDate(date) {
var newDate = new Date(date.getTime()+date.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000);

var offset = date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
var hours = date.getHours();

newDate.setHours(hours - offset);

return newDate;   
}
```

based on use convert

```
convertUTCDateToLocalDate(date).toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for your sweet answer but I want to convert utc datetime by timezoneName like 'Asia/Jakarta'.User have TimezoneName and utc dateTime only.I have convert datetime by user TimeZone name only not getTimezoneOffset.

Comment: Use moment.js with moment-timezone.

Comment: If you are going yo moment.js means function will be like this...   function toTimeZone(time, zone) {
    var format = 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss ZZ';
    return moment(time, format).tz(zone).format(format);
}

Comment: ok i have try this function like that      function toTimeZone(time, zone) {
                                                 var format = 'MM/dd/yyyyHH:mm:ss ZZ';
                                return moment(time, format).tz(zone).format(format);
                            }
                            
    var test = toTimeZone("2013-11-18 11:55", "Europe/Busingen");